# Path cannot be indexed by google

Tags: seo, urlencode

My pages contain this kind of url:
http://fashion.piliapp.com/author/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wretch.cc%2Fblog%2Fwiwinnie/
which created by
"http://fashion.piliapp.com/author/" . rawurlencode("http://www.wretch.cc/blog/wiwinnie") . "/"

HTML looks like

```
<cite><a href="/author/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wretch.cc%2Fblog%2Fwiwinnie/">♡winnie♡(｡￫v￩｡)♡</a></cite>
```

It occur lots of time on each pages, and I also added in sitemap.xml , but it only have one result in **site:fashion.piliapp.com/author/**
It should have thousands pages.

I think the problem are:
 - Google considers as those pages are typo pages.
 - CITE tag will not be indexed.
 - this kind of urls are invalid.

Shell I change anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you can change the url still, go ahead and do change it.
Just make sure everything still works fine if you change it :)

or if you want you, may use some base_encode, then base_decode techniques.

```
<?php
$url = base64_encode($url) . '.htm';
$url = "http://fashion.piliapp.com/author/" . $url;
?>
```

then when displaying the actual page, get url later by decoding it

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = str_replace("http://fashion.piliapp.com/author/",'',$url);
$url = str_replace(".htm",'',$url);

$url = base64_decode($url);
//$url should contain the actual url afterwards

?>
```